# Input and output shapes in keras ANN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to implement an ANN using keras for multiclass classification task.
This is my dataset:

> 1. features shape (9498, 17)
> 2. labels shape (9498,)

where 9498 is the number of pixels and 17 is the number of timestamps, and I have 24 classes that I want to predict.
I wanted to start with something very basic. This is the code I used:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# Loading the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(NDVI, labels, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)

# Building the model
model = Sequential([
  Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(17,),name="layer1"),
  Dense(64, activation='relu', name="layer2"),
  Dense(24, activation='softmax', name="layer3"),
])
print(model.summary())


# Compiling the model
model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',                              # gradient-based optimizer
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',               # (>2 classes)
  metrics=['accuracy'],
)

# Training the model
model.fit(
  X_train, # training data
  y_train, # training targets
  epochs=5,
  batch_size=32,
)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2f4cf6510b24> in <module>()
     23   y_train, # training targets
     24   epochs=5,
---> 25   batch_size=32,
     26 )

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    143                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    144                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 145                             str(data_shape))
    146     return data
    147 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected layer3 to have shape (24,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I don't know why this error pops. Also, I don't seem to understand the input and output shapes in keras even though I checked other similar posts that tackle the same topic.

**EDIT:** Here is a quick look into my labels:

[image: quick look into my labels]

Should I do like one hot encoding ?

Comment: The labels shape shouldn't be (9498,) but (9498, 24) if you really have 24 classes. Here you are actually specifying that you only have 1 class.

Comment: How can I fix this? Should I just use reshape?

Comment: No you should not reshape because the second dimension of 24 classes doesn't even exist. Can you show a snapshot of your labels data ? just first few rows (like 5). For that you can edit your question and include a picture or just some formatted data.

Comment: Ok, I just added that.

Comment: One more question, how come I haven't specified that y_train or y_test (i;e, labels) are the outputs and it already raises that error?

Comment: So what you have to do here is preprocess your labels data. Let me write an answer below..

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that your labels data is a one dimensional vector of shape (9498,). This means that the number of output labels is 1, and this would be a regression problem because you are predicting only one value.

On the other hand we can see that that vector contains 24 different categories of labels and this is where you would like to model a multi-classifier. So what you have to do first of all is to convert each value in the labels vector into a 24 dimensional vector. You can do this for instance by using the `scikit-learn LabelBinarizer` and here is how it works basically:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
labels = binarizer.fit_transform(labels)
print("binarized_labels.shape:", labels.shape) #-> should now return (9498, 24)
```

And now you can feed it to your model

Here's maybe a complete solution:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Loading the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(NDVI, labels, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)

# Binarize the output to have 24 class labels
binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = binarizer.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = binarizer.transform(y_test) #N.B. here you neeed only to use '.transform()' rather that '.fit_transform()'


# Building the model
model = Sequential([
  Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(17,),name="layer1"),
  Dense(64, activation='relu', name="layer2"),
  Dense(24, activation='softmax', name="layer3"),
])
print(model.summary())


# Compiling the model
model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',                              # gradient-based optimizer
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',               # (>2 classes)
  metrics=['accuracy'],
)

# Training the model
model.fit(
  X_train, # training data
  y_train, # training targets
  epochs=5,
  batch_size=32,
)
```